# Does personal hotspot always use cellular data?

Tags: wifi, iphone, tethering

If I have my iPhone connected to a wifi connection, then put it on personal hotspot, is the device I'm connecting to my iPhone with using cellular data bandwidth, or the wifi bandwidth?

You'd think it's a silly thing. But I'm JUST out of range of a wifi signal with my laptop, so my plan is to put my phone in a window not too far from my desk, and use it almost as an extender.

Comment: I had just tried this, and I looked online and came here, but my data usage (I was in the exact same scenario) skyrocketed even while my phone was on wifi.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Personal Hotspot mode detaches the device from any network and is intended to make all data flow to and from the cellular account. If you pulled the SIM card your plan just might work as a stunt to connect two laptops in the absence of another router, but it certainly won't extend an existing wireless network in the manner you describe.

Comment: That's too bad, but it's what I thought :(
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

MyWi lets you share a wifi connection over wifi. But it would require jailbreaking

Answer (score -5):

It's not a silly thing.  I just noticed that someone was connected to my iphone's hotspot while it's connected to my WIFI.  I verified my iPad to see if it was the one connected to the hotspot and it wasn't.  I guess someone close by "figured out" my hotspot's password. ALWAYS turn off your hotspot while not in use!

Comment: Has nothing to do with answering OP's question.