# Can I share my iPhone's WiFi connection to my Mac?

Tags: iphone, ios, mac, wifi, internet

I'd like to be able to share my iPhone's WiFi connection to my Mac.  I'm NOT asking to share the phone plan (the iPhone is actually being used as an old iPod).

My Mac can't connect to a wifi network because they require that you have some account that charges for it. However, the Wifi used to be free, and my iPhone still connected.  Is there a way to share the wifi connection over Bluetooth or something?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does personal hotspot always use cellular data?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63144/does-personal-hotspot-always-use-cellular-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This isn't a function of the iPhone OS from Apple. If this isn't a short term need, there might be a jailbreak tweak to turn the OS into a fully functioning router / hotspot, but the hardware isn't designed to extend a network as your use case requires.

Comment: googling "iphone as wifi repeater" (which is close to what this functionally looks like), suggests MyWi (intelliborn.com/mywi.html) can do this, but it requires jailbreaking.