# Sharing iPhone WiFi connection

Tags: ios, wifi, tethering

Is there any way to share an iPhone's Wifi connection via Bluetooth or USB? 
I know Windows PC's and MAC's can do this, but what about iPhones?

Note: Please use text descriptions instead of images.

Comment: Please add some details. Do you want to know how one can use USB tethering from iPhone to access internet over macOS and windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be found under Settings → Personal Hotspot. Password is also set there. Settings → Cellular, Personal Hotspot is also the same setting. When you turn it on, it asks if you want to turn on Wi-Fi and Bluetooth, or, USB only.

If USB is connected, one can turn on Personal Hotspot from Control Centre, it will automatically use USB to share cellular data. In Control Centre, holding down (force touch/ 3D Touch) the square block with Wi-Fi, Cellular data etc reveals two extra options of Airdrop in the bottom left and Personal hotspot in bottom right.

If USB is disconnected, Wi-Fi should remain in "on" state, but no new connections should be allowed, i.e. white state, not blue in control centre. Same for Bluetooth. This lets you share mobile data. But you cannot share iPhone's Wi-Fi connection using Wi-Fi or Bluetooth or USB.

- [Does personal hotspot always use cellular data?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63144/does-personal-hotspot-always-use-cellular-data/63146#comment511061_63146)
- [How to check if iPhone is sharing Wi-Fi network or Cellular data via hotspot?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378653/how-to-check-if-iphone-is-sharing-wi-fi-network-or-cellular-data-via-hotspot)

At times, when connected to USB, iPhone can prompt for passcode for allowing computer connected to access data on the iPhone.

Keep in mind on windows PC you need to have iTunes installed for it to trigger to ask that permission to 'Trust the PC' on the phone when connected via USB.

Comment: Can you share iPhone WiFi connection not just 4G/3G?

Comment: @LegendusMaximus Yes, but only through the rest two channels.

Comment: When  you turnon hotspot WiFi disconnects though

Comment: I posted a question to clarify/ test whether Wi-Fi connection can be shared or not. Turns out, only Cellular can be shared, not Wi-Fi. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378653/how-to-check-if-iphone-is-sharing-wi-fi-network-or-cellular-data-via-hotspot

Answer (score 5):

There are Three Methods to Share internet from iPhone to other devices as per my knowledge.

### Method 1 : Via Hotspot

- On your iPhone tap the Settings app. This may be located in a folder labeled "Utilities."
- Tap the `Cellular` option.
- Toggle `Cellular Data` **ON** if it isn't. This will need to be enabled in order to turn on the wireless hotspot.
- Tap `Set Up Personal Hotspot`

  > This button only appears if you've never used the personal hotspot before.
  >
  > After setting up your personal hotspot for the first time, the Personal Hotspot option will appear in the main Settings list.
- Click the Networks button in Windows. You'll see this in the System Tray in the lower-right corner of the screen.
- Turn on Wi-fi and Connect to the network displayed with the password shown on iPhone.

### Method 2 : Via USB Tethering

- Install **iTunes** on your computer.

  > If you're tethering your iPhone to a Windows computer, the computer will need to have iTunes installed in order to connect.
- Tap the Settings app on your iPhone. You can find this on one of your Home screens, or in the Utilities folder.
- Tap the Cellular option.
- Toggle Cellular Data on. You'll need this enabled in order to share your iPhone's internet with your computer.
- Tap Set Up Personal Hotspot option.
- Plug your iPhone into your computer's USB port.

  > you will see a prompt how to share the internet ( over USB only or wifi and bluetooth as well )
- Click the **Network** button on your computer. In Windows, you'll find this in the System Tray.
- You can now setup iPhone as a new network.

  > Click your iPhone to select it as your computer's network. Your computer will now use your iPhone's internet connection as you browse the internet.

### Method 3 : Via Bluetooth

- Follow same steps till turning on Hotspot
- go back to settings menu
- Toggle Bluetooth
- on Windows: **Click the Bluetooth button in your System Tray.** If you don't have a Bluetooth icon, your Windows computer may not have a Bluetooth adapter installed.
- Click **"Join a Personal Area Network."**
- Click the "Add a device" button. This can be found at the top of the window.
- Click your iPhone.

  > Don't Close this Window.
- Tap Pair on your **iPhone**. You may be prompted to enter a code that is displayed on the other device.
- Return to the Devices and Printers window.
- Right-click on your iPhone.
- Highlight **"Connect using" and then click "Access point."** Your Windows PC will now use your iPhone's internet connection over Bluetooth.